# Proof that $x(\mu)$ and $\lambda(\mu)$ are global minimizers to barrier function if functions are convex

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am stuck on a homework question, which consists of two parts. I would appreciate any help!

> Consider the nonlinear programming problem
> \begin{equation}
> \begin{aligned}
> & \text{minimize } & & f(x) \\ 
> &\text{subject to } & & g(x) \ge 0,
> \end{aligned}
> \end{equation}
>
> where $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ are continuously differentiable. A barrier transformation for a fixed positive parameter $\mu$ gives the problem
>
> \begin{equation}
> \begin{aligned}
> & \text{minimize } & & f(x) - \mu \sum_{i=1}^m \ln(g_i(x)). \\ 
> \end{aligned}
> \end{equation}
>
> a) Show that the first-order necessary optimality conditions for the barrier problem is  equivalent
> to the system of nonlinear equations
>
> \begin{equation}
> \begin{aligned}
>  \nabla f(x) - \nabla g(x) \lambda = 0  & &\\
>  g_i(x)\lambda_i = \mu, & & i = 1, \dots, m,
> \end{aligned}
> \end{equation}
>
> assuming that $g(x) \gt 0$ and $\lambda \gt 0$ is kept implicitly.
>
> b) Let $x(\mu)$, $\lambda(\mu)$ be a solution to the primal-dual nonlinear equations of (a)
> such that $g_i(x(\mu)) \gt 0, \; i = 1, \dots, m$, and $\lambda(\mu) \gt 0$. Show that $x(\mu)$ is a global minimizer to the barrier problem if $f$ and $−g_i, \; i = 1, . . . , m,$ are convex functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

My progress:

I know that the first-order optimality conditions are

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\nabla \mathcal{L}(x,\lambda) = 0, \text{ where } \mathcal{L}(x,\lambda) = f(x) - \mu \sum_{i=1}^m \ln(g_i(x)) - \mu \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i g_i(x) \\
&\lambda \ge 0 \\
&\lambda_i^\top g_i(x) = 0, \; i = 1,\dots,m. 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I have figured that somehow $\lambda_i = \frac{\mu}{g_i(x)}$. Then the first and second optimality conditions are satisfied. However, the third one seems to be satisfied only if $\mu = 0$. Have I interpreted something wrong here? For b), I do not know where to start except to try to prove that the barrier function is a convex function. Would also appreciate help here.

Thanks!

Comment: For a, do not write a new Lagrangian. Just set the derivative of the barrier function to $0$. For b, you propose proving that the barrier function is a convex function. How would you argue from there?

Comment: @LinAlg a) Would setting the gradient of the barrier function to 0 be equivalent to the optimality conditions though? The optimality conditions should also work on boundaries. Or is the function assumed to be unbounded?

b) If the barrier function is a convex function, the intersection of the constraints g(x) > 0 form a convex set and a local minimizer is also a global minimizer. So I only need to prove convexity.

Comment: For a you are asked about optimality conditions of the barrier function. The barrier function is not defined at the boundary (and it is also not optimal at the boundary).